# Concatenate string with Octopus variable in the config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, web-config, octopus-deploy

I have octopus variables in the config. I want to concatenate the octopus variable `#{HostName-test-site}` with `"preview-"` string

If I try the following in the config

```
 <site name="testSite" hostName="preview-#{HostName-test-site}" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
```

Will that work or is there anyother way of concatenating a octopus variable with a string ?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you enable the [Substitute Variables in Templates](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/configuration-features/substitute-variables-in-templates) feature in your step.